# Flexbox problem with formatting headings on rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create 3 rows of paragraphs with individual headings using Flexbox. The paragraphs are fine, but the heading (h2) isn't going on top of the paragraphs and instead is kind of smushed to the left of each paragraph.

Edited to add the HTML. Also I'm just trying to copy a website I liked on my local server so none of this wording is mine.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container h2 {
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: hsl(0, 11%, 16%);
}

.container p {
  position: block;
  margin: 25px;
  50px;
  75px;
  100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>First visit? Don't be skittish.</h2>
  <p>All new clients can enjoy a free first exam by mentioning this offer. We also provide discounted vaccination and treatment packages for puppies and kittens to start them on the right paw!</p>
  <h2>Boarding, Grooming & Doggie Daycare</h2>
  <p>We offer a full spectrum of boarding, grooming & doggie daycare services. Whether it's a day at the spa, a day of play, or a longer staycation, your pet is in good hands.
  </p>
  <h2>Refill Prescriptions</h2>
  <p>You're busy, so we make refills easy. We also competitively price match all of your pet's medications. Request a refill via our Chat Now feature or give us a call and we'll hop on it.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code, including your HTML

Comment: `flex` is a tool you'd use specifically to position elements adjacently. `<h2>` and `<p>` elements stack vertically by default - you wouldn't need any CSS to achieve that effect.

Comment: I'm learning flexblox and I decided to try it on this element b/c the original website used flexbox and the positioning without flexbox is more complicated, ie moving everything to the right and left, using random breaks to make sure all rows are equal. I figured flexbox would be easier for this, and it is with the exception of the heading being messed up

Comment: Is there a picture/live demo of how you're expecting it to look? By your statement, I get a feeling that what you're expecting and what you're communicating are not matching. And it would help everyone if there's a picture/demo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default **flex-direction: row** puts elements **horizontally**, changing it to **flex-direction: column** will probably fix it by making the element stack **vertically**.

Comment: I tried this but it just stacks everything in a column, whereas I want 3 short rows of text adjacent to one another, not on top of one another.

Comment: If you want to do that, you need to wrap your h2 and p in a div. You'll have 3 divs with h2 and p in each. Then your original code should work fine. You may need to add margins or max-widths to the divs to add space between them.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you simply must use flexbox for this, do it like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container h2 {
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: hsl(0, 11%, 16%);
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.container p {
  margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>First visit? Don't be skittish.</h2>
  <p>All new clients can enjoy a free first exam by mentioning this offer. We also provide discounted vaccination and treatment packages for puppies and kittens to start them on the right paw!</p>
  <h2>Boarding, Grooming & Doggie Daycare</h2>
  <p>We offer a full spectrum of boarding, grooming & doggie daycare services. Whether it's a day at the spa, a day of play, or a longer staycation, your pet is in good hands.
  </p>
  <h2>Refill Prescriptions</h2>
  <p>You're busy, so we make refills easy. We also competitively price match all of your pet's medications. Request a refill via our Chat Now feature or give us a call and we'll hop on it.</p>
</div>
```

However, you can achieve the same thing without flexbox.

[`paragraphs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) and [`headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) are [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), and they will display in this way by default.

```css
.container h2 {
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: hsl(0, 11%, 16%);
}

.container p {
  margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>First visit? Don't be skittish.</h2>
  <p>All new clients can enjoy a free first exam by mentioning this offer. We also provide discounted vaccination and treatment packages for puppies and kittens to start them on the right paw!</p>
  <h2>Boarding, Grooming & Doggie Daycare</h2>
  <p>We offer a full spectrum of boarding, grooming & doggie daycare services. Whether it's a day at the spa, a day of play, or a longer staycation, your pet is in good hands.
  </p>
  <h2>Refill Prescriptions</h2>
  <p>You're busy, so we make refills easy. We also competitively price match all of your pet's medications. Request a refill via our Chat Now feature or give us a call and we'll hop on it.</p>
</div>
```